# Change the width of the header in octopress to 100%

Tags: css, sass, octopress

I'm working on my own octopress theme i so i want to modify the header so it
can use 100% of the width in the browser. I added this to the "_styles.scss":

```
header[role="banner"] {
     background-image: url(/images/header-bg.png);
     background-repeat: repeat;
     position:relative;
     width: 100%;
}
```

But all i get is this result:

[image]

This are the entries in the default.html which is the default layout.

```
{% capture root_url %}{{ site.root | strip_slash }}{% endcapture %}
{% include head.html %}
<body {% if page.body_id %} id="{{ page.body_id }}" {% endif %} {% if page.sidebar == false %} class="no-sidebar" {% endif %} {% if page.sidebar == 'collapse' or site.sidebar == 'collapse' %} class="collapse-sidebar sidebar-footer" {% endif %}>
  <header role="banner">{% include header.html %}</header>
  <nav role="navigation">{% include navigation.html %}</nav>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      {{ content | expand_urls: root_url }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer role="contentinfo">{% include footer.html %}</footer>
  {% include after_footer.html %}
</body>
</html>
```

head.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]><html class="no-js iem7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="no-js lte-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% if page.title %}{% if site.titlecase %}{{ page.title | titlecase }}{% else %}{{ page.title }}{% endif %} - {% endif %}{{ site.title }}</title>
  <meta name="author" content="{{ site.author }}">

  {% capture description %}{% if page.description %}{{ page.description }}{% else %}{{ content | raw_content }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ description | strip_html | condense_spaces | truncate:150 }}">
  {% if page.keywords %}<meta name="keywords" content="{{ page.keywords }}">{% endif %}

  <!-- http://t.co/dKP3o1e -->
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  {% capture canonical %}{{ site.url }}{% if site.permalink contains '.html' %}{{ page.url }}{% else %}{{ page.url | remove:'index.html' | strip_slash }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical }}">
  <link href="{{ root_url }}/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="{{ root_url }}/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
  <link href="{{ site.subscribe_rss }}" rel="alternate" title="{{site.title}}" type="application/atom+xml">
  <script src="{{ root_url }}/javascripts/modernizr-2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="./javascripts/libs/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
  <script src="{{ root_url }}/javascripts/octopress.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {% include custom/head.html %}
  {% include google_analytics.html %}
</head>
```

custom/header.html:

```
<hgroup>
  <h1><a href="{{ root_url }}/">{{ site.title }}</a></h1>
  {% if site.subtitle %}
    <h2>{{ site.subtitle }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
</hgroup>
```

Does somebody know how i could solve this problem?

Best Regards

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: I didn't change the normal html files because from the documentation and the tutorials i have read i got the info that info that the style is just managed through sass and the *.scss files. Here is the source of my theme: https://www.mediafire.com/?25f4e4ebl1xcvfy

Comment: I added the html of the "default.html" above.

Comment: Is there a live example?

Comment: You'll have to restructure the CSS a bit. Octopress by default has the whole body as a fraction of the viewport on larger screens, so you'll have to remove that ability before being able to set width as 100%

Comment: @ZachSaucier you mean the "_styles.scss" right?

Comment: @LcSalazar Do you mean my theme if yes no i only test it local now.

Comment: @Cracksoldier I mean in all of the styling, I don't remember exactly where they set it

Comment: @ZachSaucier OK, I'll try it that way

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to color the background of only certain sections. You need to make sure your the header is in a different div as the body. You can try putting the `hgroup` in your `custom/head.html` and make sure that `head` has a full width.